# query performance matching calls by timestamps with no id/key

Tags: oracle, t-sql, optimization, timestamp

I've wrote this query which works but it's just slow. Does anyone have any tips on how I could make it run faster?

The `UCID` is a `CTE`. The source table itself has no indexes and the DBAs will not add indexes.

```
select     /*+ PARALLEL(6) */  *
from ucid d
inner join ucid o on

--call started no more than 15 seconds after origin call
o.segstart between d.SEGSTART - interval '60' SECOND  and d.SEGSTART

-- origin segment stopped exactly when the the destination call stopped
-- OR
-- d segment stopped within 60 seconds of o segment && the o call started             
within 5 seconds before the destination segment
and(o.segstop = d.callstop

or (o.callstart between d.SEGSTART - interval '5' SECOND and d.SEGSTART
and d.segstop between o.segstop and o.segstop + interval '60' SECOND
))
-- the number dialed on the o (origin) call is 8 or less digits
and length(o.dialed_num) <= 8
-- the origin call is a dial out
and o.origlogin is not null    and o.anslogin is null
--the destination call is answered with an unknown origin 
and d.anslogin is not null and d.origlogin is null
-- the origin is a dial out
and o.split1 = -1
-- don't match the same record
and d.CALL_DTL_REC_ID <> o.CALL_DTL_REC_ID
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include information about the indexes which exist on your table and the query plan generated by the database. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks for your response! The ucid is a CTE that runs before the select, but the source tables have no indexes and the DBAs will not add.  I can't seem to get the plan to run correctly, it seems to only show the CTE and not the select statement?

Comment: Without indexes to reduce query I/O your queries are going to run poorly. I suggest you email the query to your DBAs, copying your boss and whoever else needs to be involved, and tell them that since they won't do the normal thing to alleviate a performance problem - that is, add appropriate indexes - that database performance is now their problem. I've found that often works wonders. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access both tables in `PARALLEL` mode, than instruct `OPTIMIZER` to use `HASH` (you have to use as much parallelizing degree as you can):

```
select   /*+ PARALLEL(d 6)  PARALLEL(o 6) USE_HASH(d o)*/  *
from ucid d
inner join ucid o on

--call started no more than 15 seconds after origin call
o.segstart between d.SEGSTART - interval '60' SECOND  
and d.SEGSTART

-- origin segment stopped exactly when the the destination call stopped
-- OR
-- d segment stopped within 60 seconds of o segment && 
the o call started             
within 5 seconds before the destination segment
and(o.segstop = d.callstop

 or (o.callstart between d.SEGSTART - interval '5' SECOND 
 and d.SEGSTART
 and d.segstop between o.segstop and o.segstop + interval '60' SECOND))
-- the number dialed on the o (origin) call is 8 or less digits
and length(o.dialed_num) <= 8
-- the origin call is a dial out
and o.origlogin is not null    and o.anslogin is null
--the destination call is answered with an unknown origin 
and d.anslogin is not null and d.origlogin is null
-- the origin is a dial out
and o.split1 = -1
-- don't match the same record
and d.CALL_DTL_REC_ID <> o.CALL_DTL_REC_ID;
```

Comment: I'm just now reading on the differences between HASH and SORT-MERGE. The USE_HASH hint is causing the query to run "forever". I *think* this is because it can only be used on equals and the SORT-MERGE must be used for <,>, and between statements. It can also be how the server is configured, I know I'm limited to 6 degrees.